# Unit Tests Not Always run with new TFS 2017 Build

Tags: tfs

Just setting up TFS 2017, have used TFS 2008, 2010, and 2013.  I setup a new Build definition, and the unit tests are not always run.  In the UI the error message is

System.Exception: VSTest Test Run failed with exit code: 1

These messages are in the log file:

2017-08-11T01:45:37.5101413Z ##[error]Error: The test source file "C:\agent_work\1\s\Dev\\TestResults\Deploy_TfsService 2017-08-10 15_10_32\Out\MyUnitTests.dll" provided was not found.

I tried compare a log where they do run with one that doesn't run, and I can't seem to find out why they don't always run.   Here is my config:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrIqJ.jpg

thank you

Comment: Could this be a network issue? When the unit test fail, could your RDP to the build agent machine and check if the file(*MyUnitTests.dll*) is exist or not in the correspondingly path in the error log info?

Comment: Can you share the entire build logs?

Comment: well i'd rather not include sensitive information publicly.  but it appears when it fails the test runner wants to find the DLLs in the TestResults\Deploy_<username> 2017-08-24 15_22_23\Out\ folder - while when it is succesful, it looks for them in the bin\x64\Debug\ folder in each test project...  any idea why?

Comment: installed TFS 2017.2, seems to be working more reliably now.

Answer (score 0):

installed TFS 2017.2, seems to be working more reliably now.

Comment: Actually not very reliable with a different build definition, here is the log file:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/22e7hn4od54j6f8/logs_135.zip?dl=0